# Escaping string with spaces passed to ZSH function

Tags: zsh

I have a script on a remote machine. I SSH in and call it with `zsh my-script.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

# Load some environment variables
source $HOME/.extra

send_notification() {
  $HOME/bin/hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title="$1",message="$2"
}

# THIS WORKS
send_notification "My-Title" "My-description."

# THIS DOESN'T WORK
send_notification "My Title" "My description."
```

As you can see from the comments, when there's a space in a string when I pass it to `send_notification` function they don't get escaped properly and I get the following error from `hass-cli`:

```sh
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (My Title,message=My description.)
```

When there's no spaces in the strings it works fine. Any ideas how I can properly escape these spaces?

Answer (score 2):

There are always passed two arguments to `send_notification`, and the function passes the arguments on to hass-cli. Actually, the quotes around `$1` and `$2` are redundant, since you are using zsh, but they don't harm.

The bug therefore must be in the `hass-cli` program. Perhaps the arguments are not processed properly, so you have to fix this.

Comment: Thanks yeah I opened issue: https://github.com/home-assistant-ecosystem/home-assistant-cli/issues/351

Answer (score 1):

As coded the command becomes:

```
hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title=My Title,message=My description.
```

One easy solution would be to wrap the variable references in single quotes (inside the double quotes) like such:

```
hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title="'$1'",message="'$2'"
```

So the call becomes:

```
hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title='My Title',message='My description.'
```

This assumes single quotes don't have a special meaning for `hass-cli`, otherwise replace the single quotes with escaped double quotes:

```
hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title="\"$1\"",message="\"$2\""
```

So the command now becomes:

```
hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title="My Title",message="My description."
```

Comment: When you say that the command "is being expanded" that way, could you elaborate on what system is doing that? Because Zsh certainly isn't . . .

Comment: Sadly both those options give me `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (My Title",message="My description.")` <- that is from your second example.

Comment: In fact, even `hass-cli service call notify.alec --arguments title="My Title",message="My description."` fails with `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (Title,message=My description.)`. Maybe an issue with `hass-cli` or the way it's set up on my system. Seems to work fine on a different machine.

Comment: No same error. I run this command in an SSH session. In a non-SSH session on my main machine it works fine.

Comment: ahhhh, perhaps this isn't an issue with the script but rather the SSH call? could you update the question with a sample SSH call that does not work (ie, generates the error)?  are the arguments ('My Title', 'My description.') hardcoded in the script, or passed in via the SSH call?

Comment: The arguments are hardcoded in the script. The SSH call is simply `ssh other-machine.local 'zsh ~/scripts/my-script.sh'`

Comment: as you mentioned, perhaps something with `hass-cli` ... different setup/config, different versions?  'fraid I'm out of ideas at the moment ...